# How to design SQLite DB so it can be used for multiple languages?

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design, android-sqlite

I'm working on an Android app that for now is just in English, but in the future I want to have it support multiple languages. Most of my content will be in an SQLite database, but I can't figure out how to design it in such a way that later I can add more languages to it.

Comment: same app with multiple language ??? than you can store all language in SQLite DB

Comment: You could: **1** - have multiple dbs (one per language). **2** - have a single db with one or more tables per each language. Anyway, a database, should contain just... **data**. If you want to localize your app, you better use **localized string resources**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that hard. You need one extra table for all languages / locales that you want to support

```
id - locale
1 - de
2 - en
3 - fr
...
```

And every table that contains text that you need in different languages should have a reference (foreign key) to the locale table and then one entry per language version

```
id - id_locale - content
1 - 1 - something German
1 - 2 - something English
1 - 3 - something French
2 - 1 - something else in German
...
```

Also add a unique constraint on (id, id_locale)